# How to determine if left / right or middle click is pressed on JButton ActionPerformed in java?

Tags: java

adding mouseEventListener doesn't trigger the click method if the mouse has moved after mousedown, so I need the actionListener, but how can I determine the left, right or middle click there?

Comment: You know a button can be activated by using the Tab key to give it focus, then pressing the spacebar, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine this with an ActionListener as it responds to a button click and not a mouse press and so isn't built for this sort of test. If you need to determine which button was pressed, then you will need to use a MouseListener and query the MouseEvent object.

Comment: thank you, how am I suppose to do that?

Comment: @MrNobody: how are you supposed to do what? Use a MouseListener? [Google site:stackoverflow.com java swing mouselistener how to determine which button was pressed](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+mouselistener+how+to+determine+which+button+was+pressed)

Comment: My post has not been associated with a similar question. And I have done enough ressearch effort so I really don't understand why my question has been disabled. I believe I was very clear when I said "adding mouseEventListener doesn't trigger the click method if the mouse has moved after mousedown"

Comment: @MrNobody: for that you don't use mouseClicked but rather you use the mousePressed or mouseReleased events

Comment: @MrNobody, again a quick search: [site:stackoverflow.com java swing mouselistener mouseclicked doesn't work if mouse moves](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+mouselistener+mouseclicked+doesn't+work+if+mouse+moves) gets the desired answer

Comment: @MrNobody: I'm afraid that those are your options if you want to avoid it not working if the mouse moves.